# Loop and replace CSS with parseJSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

For a javascript lab we're supposed to use the provided html, css and images to create a randomly generated game board using parseJSON.

I have a game board of numbers that consists of css background images that I need to replace with random numbers parsed from a JSON file. I finally figured out how to access the JSON data but now I can't figure out how to loop through and dynamically replace the CSS backgrounds in each row with each new roll.

```
function roll() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.pppaul.blunus.com/process.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $(result.Roll).each(function(index, name) {
                console.log(name.value);
            });
        }
    });
}
roll();
$('#gamearea4x4').html("<div class='row1' id='ga4r11' onmouseover='ImageOnHover(this.id)' onmouseout='ImageOnOut(this.id)' onclick='ImageOnClick(this.id)'></div>");
```

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/elliotmah/pen/XdEJVJ

Comment: What is it you're getting stuck on? Need specifics.

Comment: How would I take each random number from the array and then replace the css background-url image for each div id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your JSON string into an array and loop like this:

```
var array = $.parseJSON('data');
$.each(array, function(index, item){
    // do stuff
});
```

You can set a CSS property with jQuery using the `.css()` method http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

e.g.

```
$('#tile1').css('background-image', 'url("/path/to/image")');
```